# Monge's Equations and Characteristics of $u_t + (x+u)u_x = 0$ with $u(x,0) = x$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

> Consider the nonlinear wave problem
> $$
> \begin{cases}
> u_t + (x+u)u_x = 0\\
> u(x,0) = x
> \end{cases}
> $$
>
> a) Write down Monge's equations in the for $du/d\tau$...,etc, and solve them.
>
> b) Plot the characteristics in the tx plane

So, I honestly don't know how to do this. I know the process when we have an equation of the form $u_t + c(u)u_x = 0$, but not when that function also includes x?

All I can confidently do is write Monge's equations for the problem:
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{dt}{d\tau} = 1,\\ 
\dfrac{dx}{d\tau} = x+u,\\ 
\dfrac{du}{d\tau}=0
\end{cases}
$$

Which gives that

$$
\begin{cases}
u = c_1 \text{ (const. w.r.t } \tau)\text{ and } 
\\\dfrac{dx}{dt} = x + u
\end{cases}
$$

But I don't know how to go about solving this and I'm struggling to find resources on this.

If anyone could explain what I need to do here or point me to some resources on this it would be much appreciated.

I tried to follow [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1876673/997524), as it seemed like a similar problem, however the solution I got was
$$
u(x,y) = \frac{x(1-t)}{1+t},
$$ but this doesn't work when substituted into the PDE so I must have done something wrong or perhaps that method is not what I want to be doing?

Comment: $$u = c_{1} \implies x' = x + c_{1} \implies x = - c_{1} + c_{2} e^{t} = - u + c_{2} e^{t} \implies c_{2} = (x + u)e^{-t}$$ which gives $$u = f((x + u)e^{-t})$$ and you can check satisfies the PDE. Now apply the initial condition.

Comment: @MatthewCassell Okay, I got solution $u(x,t) = \frac{x}{2e^t - 1}$, which works. So how do I sketch the characteristics? Am I right that the equation is $x = c_2e^t - u$? If so, what values can I place for $c_2$ and $u$ in order to sketch these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the PDE

$$
\begin{cases}
u_t + (x+u)u_x = 0\\
u(x,0) = x
\end{cases}
$$

we have

$$
\frac{dt}{1}=\frac{dx}{x+u}=\frac{du}{0}
$$

and solving,

$$
\cases{
u = c_1\\
e^{t + c_2} = x+c_1 \Rightarrow e^t c_3 = x + c_1
}
$$

but $c_1 = u$ and $c_3 = G(u)$, so

$$
e^tG(u) = x+u
$$

Now $G(\cdot)$ is determined according to the boundary conditions:

$$
e^0G(u(0,x))=x+u(0,x)\Rightarrow G(x) = 2x
$$

then we follow with

$$
e^t(2 u)=x+u\Rightarrow u(t,x) = \frac{x}{2e^t-1}
$$

Along the characteristic curves, $u(x,t) = c_0$ so we have

[image]